# Golang Write formated strings to file

Tags: go, slice

I'm trying to open a file that has the content:

```
MOT021L3
MLK407L3
MLK485L3
```

- I'm reading the file & creating a slice. From that slice, I want to iterate through it and remove "L3". Keeping MOT021.

I'm able to successfully print the output to the terminal but I am not sure how to add the data to a file with the same format. The output that is being written to the file is:

```
MOT021L3MLK407L3MLK485L3
```

The result I'm looking for in the new file is.

```
MOT021
MLK407
MLK485
```

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    //Read File
    n, err := ioutil.ReadFile("box_1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    a := string(n)

    sliceData := strings.Split(string(a), "\n")

    f, err := os.Create("box_2")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    //var trimmedSlice string
    for _, i := range sliceData {
        trimmedSlice := (strings.TrimSuffix(i, "L3"))
        fmt.Println(trimmedSlice)
        f.Write([]byte(trimmedSlice))
    }
    f.Close()

}
```

Comment: It seems you know how to strip the `"\n"` out when you read it. You need to add it back when writing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   in, e := os.Open("in.txt")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer in.Close()
   out, e := os.Create("out.txt")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer out.Close()
   s := bufio.NewScanner(in)
   for s.Scan() {
      out.WriteString(s.Text()[:6] + "\n")
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os#File.WriteString

Comment: Thank you. I knew I should've used bufio. I was all over the place learning the different packages. This makes everything much cleaner. Appreciate it.